# How to display: none between parent and sibling tags when using show more show less Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My markup is set up like so:

```
<div class="media-body" >
    <h5 class="media-heading">
        <strong id="head">{{$blog->Title}}</strong>
        <strong id="head2">{{$blog->Title}}</strong>
    </h5>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
```

I have 2 buttons using jquery to show and hide (which act as a show more show less) the two tags within my h5 tag. However I can't seem to use this code to ensure that the strong tag with `id="head2"`  is **not** displaying. I've tried

```
<style>

.head2
display:none;

</style>
```

I've also tried

```
<style>

strong.head2
display:none;

</style>
```

Im unsure if this has anything to do with Jquery so ive pasted that in below just in case.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#head").html(function(i, h) {
    var words = h.split(/\s/);
    return words[0] + ' <span>' + words[1] + ' </span>' +' <span>' + words[2] + ' </span>';
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#head2").hide();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#head2").show();
});
$("#hide").click(function(){
$("#head").show();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#head").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: I'm hoping you forgot the CSS curly brackets by mistake in your question above.

Comment: You should merge your jQuery code in order to get only one `$(document).ready();`. And the same for clicks events, `$("#hide").click(function(){$("#head").show();  $("#head2").hide();});`, and so on for `$("#show").click()`

Comment: I did @Anriëtte Myburgh. sorry I was rushing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're targeting a class of `.head2` in your CSS, but have an id. Use an id `#`  selector instead. For example...

```
<strong id="head2">{{$blog->Title}}</strong>
```

---

```
#head2 {
    display:none;
}
```

See [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information

Comment: I see. Thanks @sal niro (and for your quick response)